# Storing small changesets of lots of hierarchical data

Tags: database, git, data-structures, continuous-integration, database-performance

I'm prototyping an automated test system for a very large physics library, that looks at every commit pushed to the repository and then runs only the tests necessary to validate the new code changes. The resulting analysis and UI however need to show **all** tests, not just the small subset that the commit influenced, plus their recent history.
That is, it's not enough to just show: '*test $foo took 5 seconds*'
Instead I need to show: '*test $foo took 5 seconds, $bar took 7s, $baz took 9s*' as well as the results of (some, not all) preceding commits for comparison.

**Basically, I need to be able to read the whole state of all tests at an arbitrary commit X, and do so fast and space-efficient(-ish)** (many tests, lots and lots of data per test)

Given that the tests are in a hierarchy kinda like a filesystem, I'm currently attempting to store the whole thing in a Git repo, with test results mirroring the individual test files and a small extra table to save the link from code repo commit to test results repo commit.
Thanks to git's compression, this is sufficiently light in storage, however the read performance could be better.

**Is there a specialised approach for this?**
Duplicating the whole tree for every small commit would soon lead to excessive bloat, but I fear storing only the changesets and recursively reconstructing the tree's state will be too slow.
Using git for this feels wrong, plus I don't need some of git's features (e.g. the whole cryptography stuff) and I'm hoping that dropping it will lead to an increase in performance.

I've checked various graph- and tree-based approaches, but I lack the experience with them to fully decide on one.
Also, while I guess this could be stored in our postgres instance or similar - perhaps a multi-model database like ArangoDB would be a better fit?

Thanks!

Comment: `git` doesn't have any cryptography stuff built in.

Comment: Probably used the wrong term there: I meant the SHA checksums and signed commits and stuff, I don't need that for my simple data dumps and thought it might speed things up if left out or simplified.

Comment: SHA-1 is a must, without it you cannot use `git`'s storage at all. Signed commits don't hinder you if you don't use them.